# How to disable reset session between scenarios in Behat Mink?

Tags: facebook, selenium, webdriver, behat, mink

-- edit --

We have in the company website for statistics from Facebook. Login to statistics page is using Facebook account.
I have written BDD tests. Tests log into the site and test their functionality.
But Facebook does not allow frequent logging (probably for safety reasons). So when they log in each scenario, it will be blocked from Facebook.

The tests are run several times a day. Facebook account is only for login to website with statistics.

I want to ask. Is it possible to disable reset session between scenarios? Or is other solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain more. Where do you see this? Screenshot it. Have you asked Facebook about this? What code are you running at the moment? How often does this occur? Are you doing anything on Facebook or is it just a login?

Comment: This is valid question, I'm not sure who's decided to close it and why.

Comment: It depends on how you use Selenium with Behat. Generally, all you have to do is disable browser close/reopen between scenarios. Thus, cookies will persist between scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/handle-authenticated-users-in-behat-mink/

The main idea is to save/load browser cookies from/to file or to build it from scratch.